# Tooltips from Qml Button gets clipped by QQuickView boundary

Tags: qt, qml, tooltip

I have embedded a Qml Button via the QQuickView element in an existing ui-Layout

```
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
view->setSource(QUrl("Buttons.qml"));
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(container);
```

this works perfectly for the Button itself, however the Tooltip (which is slightly wider than the Button itself) gets clipped by the boundary of the QQuickView Widget.
I do understand why this behaviour occurs, however I couldn't find a solution for this problem so far.
Is there any way to attach a Tooltip to a QQuickComponent at runtime where the Tooltip is not rendered by the QQuickView but the common Qt Window renderer?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Make the `QQuickView`-Widget larger, so the Tooltip fits in it? I don't think the `Button` needs to fill it completely, does it?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not that simple as the QQuickView-Widget is part of a groupBox, so space is limited and - apart from that - making the QQuickWidget as large as required to show the full Tooltip would destroy the existing layout and entail refactoring most of the Application UI. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is facing this Problem:

This is certainly not the best way to solve this - however, it worked for my purpose: I added a custom signal `send` by adding the line `signal send (string timerAction)` to the mouseArea of the Qml Button and attached the 3 events `onEntered`, `onChanged`, `onExit` which send a String along with the emited `send`-signal, either to start a `QTimer`, to reset the very same Timer or to clear the Timer. Upon timeout of the Timer, it then spawns a `QToolTip` from within C++ with the intended Tooltip text.